# Call API endpoint repeatedly in some pages for dispatch an Vuex action

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I use NuxtJs Framework. I created an action to call endpoint and set it response's to store.
I want to call an Endpoint every 30 seconds in some of my dashboard pages. If the user navigates to pages that don't need the API call, I want to disable API call.

In my first try I use to implementing Interval in all pages I need API call data (This is work but I don't want to copy these codes in many of my components those need the API call data):

```
data: () => {
  return {
   getting: null,
  };
},
computed: {
  ...mapActions({
    myAction: "***name-of-action***",
  }),
},
created() {
  this.getData();
},
beforeDestroy() {
  clearInterval(this.getting);
},
methods: {
  getData() {
    this.getting = setInterval(() => {
      this.myAction()
    }, 30000);
  },
},
```

In my first try, I use a NuxtJs middleware and JavaScript Interval to dispatch the action, but when I navigate to pages that don't need the API call, it still calls the API (because JavaScript Interval needs be clear but Nuxt middleware don't have access to component lifecycle component destroy to clear the Interval)

```
export default (props) => {
   setInterval(() => {
     props.store.dispatch("***name-of-action***");
   }, 3000);
};
```

I want to do the best practice for this problem.

Comment: `best practice` would be to write some code to attempt solving your problem, then show that code and ask what you've done wrong - that's how stack overflow is supposed to work - one way I would do it is to not clear the interval, however, check some "condition" to see if the API call is required - not sure if that's "best practice" - but it's better than "no code"

Comment: @JaromandaX I added my code

Comment: you have two intervals, one of which is unstoppable ... that's a completely different problem

Comment: @JaromandaX No, I tried these two solutions separately not at the same time.

Comment: oh ... right ... well, that's interesting what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

I believe the less bad thing is to do a **mixin** which exposes 3 things:

- `startPolling()` :
  method that starts polling on the particular component
- `stopPolling()` :
  method that stops polling in the component
- `pollingprop() //name it as you see fit`
  computed property that always exposes the updated data, this data is calculated every time you make the call inside the mixin
- `(optional) hooks beforeRouteEnter() + beforeRouteLeave()`  [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards)
  which automatically calls the  `this.startPolling()` and the `this.stopPolling()`

Comment: This code add polling to all of my components but I need to add it to some specific component only

Comment: infact you make a polling-mixin.js , in every component you need this login you'll add it

Answer (score 0):

For solving this problem I used mixin and it became a fine solution.

I create a mixin like this:

```
// intervalMixin.js
export default {
  data: () => {
    return {
     getting: null,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapActions({
      myAction: "***name-of-action***",
    }),
  },
  created() {
    this.getData();
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.getting);
  },
  methods: {
    getData() {
      this.getting = setInterval(() => {
        this.myAction()
      }, 30000);
    },
  },
}
```

So I add this mixin to each component I want like this:

```
mixins: [intervalMixin],
```